# create histogram with multiple variables

Tags: r, histogram

I need to create a histogram of a variable, Ratio, but I also need to show two additional histograms of that variable, Ratio, broken down by Sex. I've done the following for the first:

```
hist(mydata$RATIO)
```

But how do I do the other two broken out by Female and Male?

Comment: `i <- mydata$Sex == "Female"; hist(mydata$RATIO[i])`. And for `"Male"` negate the index `hist(mydata$RATIO[!i])`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post any data, I went ahead and created some fake data to attempt to reproduce the example. I think there are two ways to do this: one using ggplot and the other using base r.

First - using base R

```
##Create mock data
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

x <- tibble(Ratio = c(rnorm(1000,15,1),rnorm(1000,5,1)),
                Sex = c(rep("Male", 1000), rep("Female",1000)))

female_df <- filter(x, Sex == "Female") ##Create a dataframe only for females

male_df <-  filter(x, Sex == "Male") ##Create a dataframe only for Males

hist(female_df$Ratio, col = "red",main = "", xlab = "Ratio") ##Female histogram

hist(male_df$Ratio, col="blue",main = "", xlab = "Ratio") #Male histogram

#If you want it is possible to combine the two histograms in the same graph

hist(female_df$Ratio, xlim = c(0,20), col = "red",main = "", xlab = "Ratio")

hist(male_df$Ratio, col="blue", add=T)
```

Using ggplot2

```
x %>% ggplot(aes(x = Ratio, fill = Sex)) + geom_histogram(color = "black", 
                  alpha = 0.5)

#OR

x %>% ggplot(aes(x = Ratio, fill = Sex)) + geom_histogram(color = "black", alpha = 0.5) + 
 facet_wrap(~Sex, scales = "free")
```

Comment: When I try the following: 'female_df <- filter(mydata, SEX == "F")' I get this error: 'Error in filter(mydata, SEX == "F") : object 'SEX' not found'. The structure of 'mydata' is: ''data.frame': 1036 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ SEX   : Factor w/ 3 levels "F","I","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ LENGTH: num  5.57 3.67 10.08 4.09 6.93 ...
 $ RATIO : num  0.15 0.147 0.269 0.185 0.165 ...'

Comment: Did you have the tidyverse library loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Another option to make a histogram by a grouping variable is to use the package called `lattice`. You first need to install this package, if you haven't already.

```
install.packages("lattice")
library("lattice")
```

Then you need to tell it what you want you want a histogram of "RATIO", and a grouping variable "Sex" in this case.

```
histogram(~RATIO | Sex, data=mydata)
```

This should work, but of course you could always write it this way if you prefer:

```
histogram(~mydata$RATIO | mydata$Sex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following to run:

```
female_df <- subset(mydata, SEX == "F") 
hist(female_df$RATIO)
```